# Ecclipse Installation Error

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to install the Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers (Mars) using the Eclipse Installer. But I am getting the below error while installing, any clues?

> ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=4 An error occurred while
>   configuring the installed items   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:282)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:523)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:328)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:709)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:2971)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:2900)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:2881)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:2775)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.ProgressPage$9.run(ProgressPage.java:550)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.ProgressPage$11$1.run(ProgressPage.java:635)
>   at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)   ERROR:
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 session context
>   was:(profile=C__Program Files_Eclipse_jee-mars_eclipse,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Configure,
>   operand=null --> [R]org.eclipse.platform.ide 4.5.1.M20150904-0015,
>   action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.MkdirAction).
>   ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives code=0 **Could not
>   create directory C:\Program Files\Eclipse\jee-mars\eclipse/dropins**.

Comment: Did you confirm whether your user account can actually create and write to the directory in the error message?

Comment: @ E-Riz, How to verify that?

Comment: I think I figured it out. I verified the my logged in user with 'whoami' command and provided full control to this user on this folder. And retried to install it, it got installed successfully. Thank you.

Comment: Why is that my installation is not actually recognized as a software that appears in the 'Installed Programs' or in the 'All Programs' ? I had to go and relaunch the same installer again to launch the eclipse ide again.